# How to catch Python exception thrown in C++ code wrapped in a boost python module

Tags: python, c++, exception, boost, decode

I have C++ code wrapped in a boost python module.

My C++ code does something like this:

```
char s[2];
s[0] = (char) 160;
s[1] = '\0';
boost::python::str bs = boost::python::str(s);
```

i.e. it attempts to create a boost Python string from a C string that contains an unprintable character (value 160).

When I run this code from Python script, I get this error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 11: invalid start byte`

which occurs as value 0xa0 (= 160) cannot be decoded.

How can I catch this error in the C++ code?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
boost::python::str bs;
try
{
    bs = boost::python::str(s);
}
catch (const boost::python::::error_already_set&)
{
    PyErr_Clear();
}
```

There's no information available from the exception type `error_already_set` - it is named this way because it means that the error is set inside the Python interpreter state.

Comment: Thanks John, but it didn't work..
Although the exception seems to be caught in the C++ code (i.e. the "catch" section is being executed), I'm still getting the python error

Comment: If you don't want to see the error in Python, call `PyErr_Clear()`.  I've updated the answer to show that.